# Configuring CORDIC ATAN Block in Simulink

Tags: fpga, simulink, xilinx

I am using the CORDIC ATAN block in Simulink. I am using this block to calculate the Phase difference.

here is the part of the model that I am using:
[image]

I am giving the input a and b as 0, and I was expecting the  value of `Phase_Signal` to be zero as well.

But apparently its not. I am getting `Phase_Signal` as  1.7277.

Please let me know, if I have configured the CORDIC block not properly.

ATAN Block Parameters:

[image]

Thanks

Kiran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expectation is just wrong. The point (0,0) has no unique phase. Every value is right.
To help your understanding, visualize a point that has coordinates which you transform from euclidic representation (a,b) into polar coordinates (r, phi). For every point EXCEPT (0,0) you get a unique r and phi for your a and b. But for (0,0) only r is uniquely identified with r = 0. But the angle could be every possible value.

So for the input (0,0) you could get any phase - not even always the same, but once 0, once 1.7 and once 0.5, or whatever (but afair the Xilinx coregen cordic cores are deterministic and stateless, so the result should be always the same, when using them).

Comment: Thanks a ton, I was thinking if both I and Q is zero, the Phase would be zero. I will have to remodel it with a Subtractor block to get the difference of Phase